# Why is the Pandas library using so much more memory on Ubuntu than MAC OS?

Tags: c, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, memory-leaks

Linux Ubuntu 22.04 -
MAC OS MOnterey 12.2.1

Python 3.10
Pandas 1.5.2
Numpy 1.23.5
Psutil 5.9.5
The same versions are installed on MAC and Linux.

I'm developing in Python on MAC, but running the code on my Linux Ubuntu server. There seems to be a difference in memory usage, which is causing the memory load in Ubuntu to quickly reach its max and kill the process.

I noticed the Pandas library to cause significant amounts of leakage, so I created the following snippet to illustrate the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import psutil
import sys
import ctypes


# Set the number of repetitions
n                   = 100000
memory_check        = 0
memory_check_prev   = 0

# Create an empty list to store the correlation values
correlation_values = []

# Create a dataframe with random float numbers
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3600, 2), columns=['Column1', 'Column2'])

# Perform the correlation calculation for each repetition
for _ in range(n):


    ### Correlation
    correlation     = df['Column1'].corr(df['Column2'])
    ### Percentual Change
    # df['returns']   = df['Column1'].pct_change()
    ### Filter dataframe based on idx values
    # df2             = df.loc[200:500]
    ### Filter dataframe based on str idx
    # df2             = df.loc[str(200):str(500)]


    # Malloc Trim
    if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
        malloc_lib = ctypes.CDLL('/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6')
    else:
        malloc_lib = ctypes.CDLL('/Users/koen/libcustommalloc.dylib')
    malloc_lib.malloc_trim.argtypes = [ctypes.c_size_t]
    malloc_lib.malloc_trim.restype  = None
    malloc_lib.malloc_trim(0)

    # memory checks
    memory_check    = psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 1000000000
    if memory_check != memory_check_prev:
        print('New total memory load: ' + str(memory_check))
        memory_check_prev = memory_check
```

As for the malloc_lib file >> On linux, the path above should work by itself. On MAC, a .dylib file needs to be created with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc/malloc.h>

void malloc_trim(size_t pad) {
    malloc_zone_t *zone = malloc_default_zone();
    malloc_zone_pressure_relief(zone, pad);
}
```

After creating this file, adjust the path in the Python code above to where you stored it.

---

This code results in the following memory usages per function mentioned in the code:
[image: Memory test results]

As shown in the prev image, using Malloc Trim on MAC handles the memory well with some functions.
All other options increase memory usage.

Additionally, I executed a memory analysis using Memray for the Correlation function, from which you can view the results here:
[Memray memory leaks report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glzGw.png)
The lowest level indicates memory to be leaking at the
`'dot at <__array_function__internals>'` 
line, blocking me from any further analysis.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your program runs to completion with essentially constant memory use (per its own self-reporting) on my CentOS Stream 8 Linux workstation.  With both the system's default Python 3.6, and with the CentOS-provided Python 3.9.  I ran it as-is, but for changing the path to the system's libc.

Comment: Same if I remove the `malloc_trim()` usage, and in this case the total memory usage seems to be literally constant, as the memory check only reports a different load twice, very early.

Comment: And even with the `malloc_trim()` engaged, I see only a few different memory loads reported if I pull the `malloc_trim()` setup out of the loop (and after all, it doesn't make sense to load the library and set up the function anew every time you want to call it).

Comment: Thnx John. I re-tested with the Malloc_Trim() pulled out of the loop and this showed quite some improvement on MAC, but still leakage on Linux Ubuntu 22.04. I also notice very little memory changes when I deactivate Malloc_Trim entirely, but still roughly 1% memory increase over the whole test. Point is that my actual process contains many more Pandas functions and therefore, this 1% leads to significant impact.

Comment: What library versions are you using for Pandas and Numpy @John? How much % leakage do you notice on CentOS Stream 8 Linux workstation? Might be worth considering to change Linux OS if that makes a difference.

Comment: As a variation, I tried a different Pandas function instead of the correlation calculation:
`df['returns']   = df['Column1'].pct_change()`

This resulted:  
- Ubuntu 22.04 >> w/wo Malloc: 11.68% / 11.09%
- MAC 12.2.1      >> w/wo Malloc: 6.17% / -37.76%

Malloc_trim seems to have a drastic effect on MAC, but hardly any on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by taking out the Anaconda environment and run the code in the default python installation in Linux Ubuntu 23.
Now memory usage is stable, with or without the malloc_trim function.

As I made sure all packages have the same versions, I'm not sure what the problem in Anaconda was. If I figure this out later, I will update this answer accordingly.